# Errors running yeoman AngularJS generator

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman

**Any help greatly appreciated!**

While trying the following steps from http://yeoman.io/ I got lots of errors on running `yo angular` that instructed me to post [this issue on github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5026).

The steps I was following at http://yeoman.io/:

```
npm install -g generator-angular  # install generator
yo angular                        # scaffold out a AngularJS project
bower install angular-ui          # install a dependency for your project from Bower
grunt test                        # test your app
grunt serve                       # preview your app (formerly `grunt server`)
grunt                             # build the application for deployment
```

My npm and node versions:

```
$ npm -v
1.4.3
$ node -v
v0.10.26
```

The output starting a little before the first error:
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.1
    npmnpm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
     ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npmnpm http  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
    ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm npm http GETERR! https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign
 cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/js-yaml/examples/custom_types.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/js-yaml/examples/custom_types.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/iconv-lite/README.md~'
npm npm ERR!ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
 Error: ENOENT, chmod '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/which/package.json'
npm npm ERR!ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
 If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npmnpm  ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>


npm npmERR!  SystemERR! Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
 System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm npm ERR! ERR! commandcommand "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
 "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npmnpm  ERR! ERR!cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/which/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/which/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
 cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/iconv-lite/README.md~
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/iconv-lite/README.md~
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/underscore.string/Rakefile'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/underscore.string/Rakefile
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/underscore.string/Rakefile
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.3
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/test/findup-sync_test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/test/findup-sync_test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/test/findup-sync_test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/getobject/test/namespace_test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/getobject/test/namespace_test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/getobject/test/namespace_test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/async/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/async/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/async/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffee-script/extras/jsl.conf'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffee-script/extras/jsl.conf
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/coffee-script/extras/jsl.conf
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/exit/test/exit_test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/exit/test/exit_test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/exit/test/exit_test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/hooker/dist/ba-hooker.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/hooker/dist/ba-hooker.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/hooker/dist/ba-hooker.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-legacy-util/test/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-legacy-util/test/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-legacy-util/test/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/glob/glob.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/glob/glob.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/glob/glob.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/1.1.2
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/dateformat'
File exists: /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/dateformat
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/dateformat
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/dateformat/Readme.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/multiparty/2.2.0
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back  grunt@0.4.4 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/iconv-lite'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/iconv-lite
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno 53
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/rimraf/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/rimraf/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-48-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pullstream
```

no errors here..

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options

> ws@0.4.31 install /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
make: Entering directory `/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'

> optipng-bin@0.3.3 postinstall /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node index.js

✗ getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs

> gifsicle@0.1.5 postinstall /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/gifsicle
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@0.1.7 postinstall /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@0.2.6 postinstall /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lpanebr/mysites/webdev/public/angular/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
lpanebr@brain:~/mysites/webdev/public/angular
$
```

Comment: I believe the npm registry may have been down when you tried. If you try again now do you get the same result?

Comment: yes, but the sequence the errors appear is not the same and the error does not happen on the same packages..

Comment: Odd. Well it's been 7 hours since you asked this question now and I've definitely been using the npm registry successfully in that time, so that must not be it.

Comment: You're a couple patch revisions behind with npm. Maybe try running `npm update -g npm` to catch it up and then see if you get the same errors.

Comment: @AlexFord Yesterday I `sudo apt-get purge nodejs` and then reinstalled it but the problem persisted. Just now I tried `yo angular` and all went well with no errors. (go figure...)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by upgrading to the latest stable version of node with [these instructions](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs).

Beforehand I was running node 0.10.28 and npm 1.4.< something >-alpha.